# How does the country path drupal module work?

Tags: drupal-7, multilingual

I want my Drupal site to be divided:

```
/uk/en
/uk/fr
/us/en
/us/es
```

Based on [this advice](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104778/creating-multi-country-website-where-each-countrys-site-is-multilingual), I was told to use [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/country_path). The problem is, the module has no configuration page, nor does it have a README. I have scanned the code and it's not immediately apparent how to use it with the Domain Module.

Anybody been able to use this and get it working as described above?

Answer (score 1):

Multilingual support is provided by the **Locale** core module. To add a new locale(country/language combination) enable the **Locale** module.

Go to *Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Languages*
and add the new locales you need.
Specifically **Path prefix language code** value will be used to build the url.

Answer (score 0):

Country Path module extends domain access module. You do not have to configure anything except checking 'country path' in '**configuration->languages->detection and selection**'. The country suffix will be added automatically based on the country domain selected in your domain record.
Example: I had created three domain records for india australia and singapore with the same URL and was able to access all the three by prefixing /in /au  and /sg respectively